# how to create pagination and sorting with search functionality in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to create search functionality with pagination and sorting. But I don't know how to do this in CodeIgniter. Following is my controller function:

```
function view($page = 1,$sort='emp_id',$order='asc'){
    $data['title']='View Employee';
    $data['active']='Employee';
    $search=$this->input->post('search');        
    $num_rows=$this->employeeModel->empCount();
    $config['base_url'] ='employee/view';       
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] =5;              
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);          
    $arr=array(
        'limit'      =>$config['per_page'],
        'start'      =>(($page-1) * $config['per_page']),
        'sort'       =>$sort,
        'order'      =>$order,         
        'search'     =>$search           
        );        
    $data['search']=$search;         
    $data['empDetails']=$this->employeeModel->getEmp($arr);        
    ($this->input->is_ajax_request())? $this->load->view('ajaxFiles/viewEmp',$data): $this->template->load('templates/template','HR-Admin/viewEmp',$data);        
}
```

following is view code

```
   <form action="<?php echo base_url().'employee/view' ?>" method="GET">
                <input  type="search" name="search" id="search" value="<?php if(!empty($search)){echo $search;} ?>" placeholder="Search" />
                <input  type="submit" name="" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>

<table id="emp_table" width="100%" border="1" class="table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">                
            <thead>
                <?php if($this->session->userdata('emp_role')=='Admin'){ ?>
                <tr>
                   <form action="<?php echo base_url().'employee/delete'; ?>" name="multiple_delete"  method="post" >      
                       <td colspan="10"><input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" style="float: right" value="Delete All" /></td>                       
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr class="ajax_request">
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th><a href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/view/'.$page_num.'/first_name/'.$order; ?>">Employee Name</a></th>
                    <th><a href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/view/'.$page_num.'/emp_role/'.$order;?>">Employee Role</a></th>
                    <th><a href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/view/'.$page_num.'/shift/'.$order; ?>">Employee Shift</a></th>
                    <th><a href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/view/'.$page_num.'/emp_position_id/'.$order; ?>">Employee Designation</a></th>
                    <th>Profile Picture</th>
                    <th>Action</th>                                
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="values">
        <?php  $cur_page = $this->uri->segment(3) ? intval($this->uri->segment(3)) : 1;
               $i = (($cur_page-1) * 5) +1;
            foreach($empDetails as $val){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ucfirst($val['first_name']).' '.ucfirst($val['last_name']); ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $val['emp_role']; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $val['shift_type']; ?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $val['position']; ?></td>  
                    <?php if(empty($val['profile_img'])){ ?>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/user_image.png'; ?>" alt="Profile Img" width="80px" height="80px" /></td>
                    <?php } else{ ?>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url().$val['profile_img']; ?>" alt="Profile Img" width="80px" height="80px" /></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/empProfile/'.$this->encrypt->encode($val['emp_id']); ?>"><button class="btn btn-info">View Profile</button></a>
                        <a title="Edit" href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/edit/'.$this->encrypt->encode($val['emp_id']); ?>"><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button></a>
                    <?php if($this->session->userdata('emp_role')=='Admin') { ?>                                
                        <a title="Delete" onclick="return confirm_delete()" href="<?php echo base_url().'employee/delete/'.$this->encrypt->encode($val['emp_id']); ?>"><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></a>                   
                        <input type="checkbox" name="multi_del[]" id="multi_del" value="<?php echo $val['emp_id']; ?>" />                            
                    <?php } ?>                           
                    </td> 
                </tr>
        <?php $i++;  } ?>
            </tbody>
             </form>
        </table>
        <ul class="ajax_request"> <?php echo  $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></ul>
```

and following is my script for ajax pagination

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajax_request a").click(function() {
        $("#resultDiv").load(this.href);
        return false;
    });         
  });       
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i did google but i can't find any proper solution about this...

Comment: Use datatables for this.

Comment: thanks@pramod i know about datatables , But i want to do this without using datatables

Comment: Please also post your view code, since you need to create the pagination links there. I don't see you loading the pagination library anywhere, so i assume you do that in your constructor?

Comment: @Jeroen van Veghel pagination library is autoloaded

Answer (score 0):

Use following library for use datatables.js with codeigniter. Here you can do search and sorting.

[Codeigniter Datatables](https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables)